# razor - get list of sections

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, asp.net-mvc-4

Is there a way to get a list of sections defined in a layout file?  For example, if I want to know what sections are defined in my Shared/_Layout.cshtml file is there a way to parse that Layout file so that I know what sections exist in the layout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no built-in function I'm aware of because the name isn't necessarily known without executing the view.

You can probably just run a regular expression over your layouts, like

```
[^@]@RenderSection\(\s*"(?<name>[^"]+)"\s*\)
```

which accepts @RenderSection("foo") or @RenderSection(  "foo"   ), but skips @@RenderSection (the @@ escaped @).

However, this assumes that the name of the section is passed in as a string literal. The view could also look like (not your typical situation, but possible):

```
@RenderSection(Model.SectionName)
```

In that case you're pretty much lost.

Comment: This looks like it could work.  What's the best way to read the Layout as a string?

Comment: You'll only know the layout when the view is already rendering (except you provide a master explicitly when you return a view result from your action), which could make the whole idea a bit tricky. If you know the (virtual) path to the layout, you can use [File.ReadAllText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.io.file.readalltext.aspx).

Comment: So I'm trying to test the regex like this:
Regex layoutRegex = new Regex("[^@]@RenderSection\(\s*"(?<name>[^"]+)"\s*\)");
            var sections = layoutRegex.Matches(layoutAsString);

but I'm getting an error - "Unescaped escape sequence".  Am I trying to test this wrong?

Comment: The regex string contains backslashes and double quotes, try either `"[^@]@RenderSection(\\s*\"(?<name>[^\"]+)\"\\s*)"` or `@"[^@]@RenderSection(\s*""(?<name>[^""]+)""\s*)"`

Comment: I'm not getting zero matches with both regular expressions.  My test string looks like this:  "</head><body>    @RenderSection(\"TestSection\", false) </body></html> "

Comment: `"[^@]@RenderSection\\(\\s*\"(?<name>[^\"]+)\"\\s*(?:,\\s*(?:true|false)\\s*)?\\)"`

Comment: @Andre slightly revised, `@"(?<!@)@RenderSection\(\s*""(?<name>\w+)""\s*(?:,\s*(?:true|false)\s*)?\)"`